# Как отсортировать целые числа от 1 до n так, чтобы каждое число, начиная со второго, делило сумму чисел, стоящих левее него, нацело

Tags: python, алгоритм, математика, олимпиада

Массив всегда начинается с 1 и заканчивается каким-нибудь `n` и числа идут по порядку

Наример, есть массив `[1,2,3,4,5]`
на выходе должно получится `[3,1,4,2,5]`

P.S. Имеется ограничение по времени - 1 секунда, а максимальная длина массива может быть до 10000 чисел (все числа идут по порядку и не повторяются)

Вот что пока выходит:

```
def check(a): #проверка подходит массив под условие или нет
    E = a[0]
    out = False
    for i in a[1:]:
        if(E%i==0):
            out = True
        if(E%i!=0):
            return False
        E=E+i
    return out


def sort(arr): #сортировка, тут у нас простой перебор комбинаций 
    n = len(arr) 
    for a in range(n):
        for b in range(n):
            if(b==a): continue 
            E = arr[b] #сумма чисел стоящих левее
            for c in range(n):
                if(c==b): continue
                if(E%arr[c]!=0): #если сумма чисел стоящих левее делится на текущее нацело то меняем текущее и предыдущее числа местами
                    temp = arr[c-1]
                    arr[c-1] = arr[c]
                    arr[c] = temp
                if(check(arr)): return arr #если массив проходим проверку возвращаем его

                E=E+arr[c]
```

Comment: Это вопрос не по программированию, а по математике.

Comment: @VladD, обоснуйте

Comment: А это интересная задачка!

Comment: Это задача на алгоритмизацию, т.е. все-таки, по программированию)

Comment: Задачка-то чисто переборная... я бы реализовывал её рекурсивной функцией. На вход подаётся накопленный вектор и остаток, функция пробует пристыковать к вектору каждое из чисел остатка, и если делимость сохранилась - передаёт результат на следующий уровень. Если на уровень поступил пустой остаток - выводим очередное решение. Или можно реализовать нерекурсивно - тут бы я взял за основу метод ветвей и границ.

Comment: *Вот что пока выходит* Подробно откомментируйте свой код, объясните его логику. А то создаётся впечатление, что он никак не соотносится с задачей, и ляпнут в вопрос исключительно для того, чтобы его не закрыли за отсутствие попытки решить самостоятельно.

Comment: *на выходе должно получится [3,1,4,2,5]* Или [5,1,2,4,3]...

Comment: @Akina,  _[3,1,4,2,5] Или [5,1,2,4,3]_ - да верно, возможных комбинаций может получится несколько, но для задачи можно взять любую подходящую

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Окончательный ответ. На С++, правда :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    int m = N/2;
    for(int i = 1; i <= m; ++i)
        cout << (m+i) << " " << i << " ";

    if (N % 2) cout << (2*m+1);

    cout << endl;
}
```

Итак, если это `N = 2m`, то мы пишем числа

```
m+1, 1, m+2, 2, ..., 2m, m
```

Если `N = 2m+1`, то

```
m+1, 1, m+2, 2, ..., 2m, m, 2m+1
```

Всё.

Промежуточный ответ не вытираю, все ж таки пример перебора с возвратом - иногда годится. Да и о том, как прочищает мозги информация о том, что решение существует - тоже :)

Прошу обратить внимание - сами видите, что условие "до 10000, 1 секунда" автоматом наводит на совсем другие рассуждения :) **Никогда не ленитесь выкладывать полное условие!**

Comment: Спасибо огромное!! оказывается так всё просто было)

Answer (score 6):

Реализация алгоритма @Harry на Python:

```
def div_sort(array):
    m = N // 2
    result = []
    for i in range(0, m):
        result.append(array[m+i])
        result.append(array[i])
    if N % 2:
        result.append(array[N-1])
    return result


N = int(input('N = '))
print(div_sort(range(1, N+1)))
```

Если вместо перестановок элементов исходного массива генерировать результирующий "на лету", то можно несколько упростить код:

```
def div_sort(N):
    m = N // 2
    result = []
    for i in range(1, m+1):
        result.append(m+i)
        result.append(i)
    if N % 2:
        result.append(N)
    return result


N = int(input('N = '))
print(div_sort(N))
```

Comment: @elena Примите, пожалуйста, ответ Harry, а не мой. Задачу решил именно он. Я просто перевёл решение на Python.

Comment: вместо result.append можно просто yield использовать. Вызов: `print(*divsum_sorted_range(N))`

Answer (score 4):

Как промежуточный ответ - явно есть какой-то точный алгоритм, который мне пока не известен - есть метод перебора с возвратом. Полный перебор заткнется уже на втором десятке окончательно...

Мы просто перебираем варианты - подставляя поочередно первое число, в качестве второго - только те, которые удовлетворяют условию, потом третьи для этих двух - так мы отсечем львиную долю негодных комбинаций... но все равно это будет слишком долго.

На python'е не умею, вот этот перебор с возвратом на C++:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

vector<bool> v;

bool test(vector<bool>&b, int n, vector<int>&r)
{
    if (n == b.size())
    {
        for(auto i: r) cout << setw(3) << i; cout << endl;
        return true;
    }
    int sum = accumulate(r.begin(),r.end(),0);
    for(int j =0; j < b.size(); ++j)
    {
        if (b[j] == false)
        {
            if (sum % (j+1) != 0) continue;
            b[j] = true;
            r.push_back(j+1);
            bool res = test(b,n+1,r);
            r.pop_back();
            b[j] = false;
            if (res) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) v.push_back(false);

    vector<int> r;
    test(v,0,r);

}
```

[Тут](https://ideone.com/LieTMh) действующий пример для 35. Как видите, для 10000 не вариант...

Можно ускорить, беря числа в обратном порядке - но все равно ненамного:

https://ideone.com/1c9Z5T

Answer (score 1):

Саааамый простой вариант — написать функцию, которая проверяет, является ли массив отсортированным «как надо», и подать ей на вход все возможные перестановки этого массива (а их можно получить с помощью библиотечных функций, кстати). Это будет т.н. «переборный алгоритм».

Между прочим, не исключено, что подходящих перестановок и не будет, т.е. данный конкретный массив отсортировать «как надо» невозможно. (В обычной сортировке такого не бывает =)

Когда у вас в руках будет «какой-нибудь» корректный (проверьте это) алгоритм решения задачи, имеет смысл подумать, а нужно ли его оптимизировать по числу операций. Может быть и нет ;)

Comment: та это понятно.. но будет очень долго работать если перебирать все варианты

Comment: а какие у вас есть требования по времени работы? а вы уже пробовали?)

Comment: по времени есть ограничение секунда, и массив по длине может достигать 10000 чисел

Comment: тогда да, переборный не подходит ;)

Comment: существует `n!` перестановок (факториал быстро растёт: `n!` содержит ~n цифр). Даже для n=20 за секунду решение не найдётся